# audio.stackexchange.com redirects to avp.stackexchange.com, not sound.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed

Now that the new Sound site is up, should't http://audio.stackexchange.com redirect to http://sound.stackexchange.com instead of http://avp.stackexchange.com?

Or will this break something?

Comment: We're going to fix this as we rename video (video currently is a redirect to avp as well, so we have to take that down, fix the audio redirect, move this to video, then make AVP a redirect). I'm getting with Dalgas tomorrow and will post a more proper answer then, once I'm sure we're sure on precisely how we're proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to get fixed [as we re-brand AVP into video](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/moving-avp-to-video-se-next-steps) at the end of the week. It's likely that both the audio *and* the video redirects will stop working for a short while, but this is what it'll look like redirect wise once we're done:

- *video.stackexchange.com* - this site, no longer a redirect
- *avp.stackexchange.com* -> *video.stackexchange.com*
- *audio.stackexchange.com* -> *sound.stackexchange.com*

It shouldn't be wonky for much longer.

Comment: Couldn't find audio.stackexchange.com

The Q&A site audio.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet.